# C++Builder ExeName & ParamStr(0) with relative Final output directory setting

Tags: c++builder-11-alexandria

I wrote a test application to investigate the effects of setting Final output directory to a location outside of the project file directory tree on Application->ExeName and ParamStr(0).

What I have observed is as follows.

If the Final output directory is a relative path - default is .\$(Platform)\$(Config) - then this is appended to the project file path.

For my test project file:
C:\Project\Suite\Project1\Project1.cbproj
this will result in ExeName & ParamStr(0) =
C:\Project\Suite\Project1\.\Win32\Debug\Project1.exe.

Again this is under the debugger. Selecting Run Without Debugging or run outside the IDE these will both have the correct value C:\Project\Suite\Project1\Win32\Debug\Project1.exe.

If I set the Final output directory to:
..\Target\$(Platform)\$(Config)
to put the exe in following directory,
C:\Project\Suite\Target\Win32\Debug
the resulting value of ExeName & ParamStr(0) =
C:\Project\Suite\Project1\.\..\Win32\Debug\Project1.exe
which is clearly not helpful as the Project1.exe makes use of ExeName to determine the directory that the exe is in, and the related directories where various shared configuration and application specific files are kept.

Using GetCurrDir() on startup instead of ExeName is a possible workaround. I have tested this and it seems to work correctly irrespective of whether or not the program is run with debugging.

The reason to do this is that there are several dynamic and static libraries as well as executable programs in the suite - Project2, Project3, etc. Compiling the .dll and .exe files into a common location allows for a single location of shared application support files.

It is also possible to set an absolute path in the Final output directory. Doing so will cause the ExeName and ParamStr(0) value to be correct however when someone else loads the suite onto their computer they may not put it in exactly the same path. Currently the Suite can be placed anywhere and the developer can build all without having to change any path settings.

Update: Apart from the ExeName problem, debugging an exe that uses a .dll in this "external" directory can't happen because under the debugger with the faulty ExeName the executable can't find .dlls despite them being in that folder. Run Without Debugging also fails to find the .dll files. Running this .exe from outside IDE works. Setting the Working Directory to the Target .exe path (absolute) works. Using a relative doesn't work.

It would be good to know why the IDE behaves this way and whether this is something that could be improved or otherwise whether there is another way around this.

Comment: `TApplication::ExeName` simply calls `ParamStr(0)`, which in turn simply calls `GetModuleFileName(NULL)`, which reports the full path to the module that created the calling process, as it is known by the OS. So, the path should always be valid and accurate.  Whether it contains extra `.` and `..` in it is another matter.

Comment: Hi Remy - as always, thank you for your input.

This is not what I am seeing. Setting a relative value in "Final output directory" that is outside the project file directory tree results in an ExeName value that is the concatenation of the project file path with the relative path being reported by the application. I imagine that the debugger is setting a parameter with this when it starts the process.

My test project is on OneDrive here:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjROG9fNzRVXhrwMXGlN4PMW5_g1Vw?e=P9SORt

Comment: Nevertheless, what I described is what really happens. Look at the RTL's source code: `function TApplication.GetExeName: string; begin Result := ParamStr(0); end;` ... `function ParamStr(Index: Integer): string; var ... Buffer: array[0..260] of Char; begin Result := ''; if Index = 0 then SetString(Result, Buffer, GetModuleFileName(0, Buffer, Length(Buffer))) else ... end;` And per [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew): "*If [hModule] is NULL, GetModuleFileName retrieves the path of the executable file of the current process*"

Comment: Nothing the IDE does should be affecting what `GetModuleFileName(0)` reports.

Comment: I think the debugger (or IDE) is passing whatever is in Final output directory to a CreateProcessW() call - probably to the lpApplicationName parameter, which can be a full or partial path as noted in the documentation:  "The string can specify the full path and file name of the module to execute or it can specify a partial name. In the case of a partial name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to complete the specification. The function will not use the search path. This parameter must include the file name extension; no default extension is assumed."

Comment: For the IDE, the current directory will be the project file (.cbproj) directory.

In my test project this will be "C:\Project\Suite\Project1\"   then add the partial Final output directory  "..\Target\Win32\Debug"    plus    "\Project1.exe"   which gives exactly what a call to GetCommandLine() returns.

For what I want to do, the IDE would have to resolve the current directory and relative path to an absolute path for the final output and pass that to the created process and probably set the Working Directory with an absolute path as well.

Comment: I could make this work by using absolute paths in Final output directory and Working directory across all of 16 different projects (at least the .exe and .dll modules) but then every programmer would either need to install in the same location or update all of the projects to match their installed path.

Comment: the path that `GetModuleFileName()` returns, and what `GetCommandLine()` returns, are two completely different and unrelated things.

Comment: Yes. But because of the paramters provided by the IDE and the way CreateProcess treats these parameters, these calls return exactly the same thing, for my example at least.

Comment: Reading through the CreateProcess documentation and the way lpApplicationName is treated explains why there is an extra ".\" in the ExeName / ParamStr(0) value. For run with debugging at least. It appears to work differently for Run without debugging - ExeName is correct, but GetCommandLine is still wrong. I haven't been able to find any detailed information on this. I guess what I am trying to do is not a use case that Embarcadero has considered.